# Reduce function appears to be off by 1 when counting properties in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a csv file [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60220533/neo_test2_00_SO.csv), which once read into Neo4J using the commands at the bottom of this post, creates a set of 4 family trees.

Over all families, I would like to return the `family_id` for a family having 2 or more people where `is_ill` = '1'.

When I look a priori, I can easily see what my expected results will be, just with some quick filtering in excel to show only nodes where `is_ill` = '1'.

[image]

You can see that there are 8, 3, and 3 appearances of `is_ill` = '1' for fam1, fam2, and fam4. So, if I write my query correctly, I'd expect to get 3 `family_id`'s back.

So, I'm all ready to practice some Cypher. Here's what I've got:

```
MATCH p=(:Person)-[]->(:Person)
WHERE 2 <= REDUCE(s = 0, x IN NODES(p) | CASE WHEN x.is_ill = '1' THEN s + 1 ELSE s END)
WITH p
RETURN distinct([x IN nodes(p) | x.family_id][0]) as Family_ID
;
```

This looks great. Except for the fact that I realize it is returning a ton of subgraphs, and I have to use this hacky `distinct()` and index `[0]`. That makes me nervous, but I can never tell when it is or isn't a good idea to do a full graph traversal, and when Cypher is going to return a slew of subgraphs or not.

But I digress. The crux of my problem is that for some reason this query returns only

```
| Family_ID |
|-----------|
| fam2      |
```

How? I clearly asked it to count up how many times the full path has nodes with that property.  The key is `2 <= ...`. That's exactly what I want!! And, if Cypher is returning `fam2`...why not also `fam3`? They have the same number of occurrences of my property!

I can monkey around and get the results I want, if I change it to `1 <= ...`. Why does this work? The counting is off by one??

Should `s = 0` be indexed differently for some reason? That doesn't seem likely. Perhaps my initial `MATCH p=(:Person)-[]->(:Person)` is undershooting the target, and I'm missing nodes? I don't think so either. There must be some problem with the way `REDUCE` is being applied.

```
//LOAD UP THE CSV
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM
'file:///...neo_test2_00.csv' AS line
CREATE (
person:Person {
 date_of_birth: line.`date_of_birth`
,does_forget: line.`does_forget`
,family_id: line.`family_id`
,father_person_id: line.`father_person_id`
,first_name: line.`first_name`
,gender: line.`gender`
,is_ill: line.`is_ill`
,is_proband: line.`is_proband`
,last_name: line.`last_name`
,mother_person_id: line.`mother_person_id`
,pidn: line.`pidn`
,subject_person_id: line.`subject_person_id`
}
)

// create parent relationship for mother
MATCH (m:Person),(s:Person)
  WHERE
(
m.family_id = s.family_id
AND
m.subject_person_id = s.mother_person_id
)
CREATE (m)-[:PARENT_OF]->(s)
;

// create parent relationship for father
MATCH (f:Person),(s:Person)
  WHERE
(
f.family_id = s.family_id
AND
f.subject_person_id = s.father_person_id
)
CREATE (f)-[:PARENT_OF]->(s)
;
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not use aggregation?

```
MATCH (p:Person {is_ill: '1'})
WITH p.family_id AS familyId, 
     COUNT(p) AS illCount WHERE illCount >= 2
RETURN familyId, 
       illCount
```

P.S. Your query returns a pattern for two `ill` people. Look at this query:

```
MATCH p=(:Person {is_ill:'1'})-[]->(:Person {is_ill:'1'})
RETURN p
```

Comment: Could the first one be modified to return the whole tree that meets the criteria? This is great stuff...thanks!